# How to configure wordpress application in subdirectory with simple php application using .htaccess / Apache2?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to configure a Wordpress application with a simple php application. The directory structure of the application is as follow :

Root directory : /var/www/demoApp/

Wordpress directory : /var/www/demoApp/wordpress/

Here i want to access the wordpress application using route http://BASE_URL/wordpress. But i am not able to configure the htaccess file. All the php pages under /var/www/demoApp/ directory are working fine using url http://BASE_URL/. While wordpress files are not being loaded correctly.

Here is my Apache configuration block :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/demoApp

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/demoApp>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

What should be the .htaccess file?

Comment: Nitesh, did you put the wordpress url into the wordpress configuration? I mean Settings/General.  Wordpress will always use this setting regardless of htaccess. Try that please and let me know.

Comment: You sure you want `AllowOverride None` in `<Directory /var/www/demoApp>` ? That'll prevent the .htaccess file from changing anything won't it?

Comment: @PeterMatisko Yes, The wordpress home page is working fine. The other pages are not working properly. like http://BASE_URL/wordpress/2017/03/11/hello-world/.
It throws apache error with no page found.

Comment: worpress uses its own .htaccess file to rewrite urls to transform the structure into GET vars. You have to work accordingly with it (you can modify it, but your 2 files must be compatible in their functioning)

Comment: @CD001 I don't know much about Apache or .htaccess. I am more familiar with Nginx. So don't know how Apache works.

Comment: Try setting it to `AllowOverride All` - it's possible you're actually preventing WordPress's own .htaccess file from doing anything : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: @CD001 Tried removing AllowOverride All. It's still the same.

Comment: Nitesh, Wordpress uses its htaccess to transfer all these urls into index.php,  the issue is there, either htaccess is missing, or it is not applied due to other  settings. Try what CD001 suggested.  Check this:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: .htaccess is present in the wordpress directory.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

And i have also removed  AllowOverride All from the config file.

Comment: @Nitesh - nah, you don't want to remove it, you want to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory /var/www/demoApp>` block (and restart the server). Otherwise, it looks like it *should* resolve properly at `http://localhost/wordpress`

Comment: I guess I also need to update .htaccess file in the /var/www/demoApp directory. But I am not sure what code should go there.

Comment: Check the link I shared before. Then, to be sure that the htaccess is actualy read by Apache, make a mistake somewhere and see if Apache yells at you. If not, you will have to include AllowOverride All

Comment: @CD001 Okay. My bad. I have added AllowOverride All. 
It's working now. But the assets like css, js, and images are broken.

Comment: For that one you're probably going to need to refer to @PeterMatisko link about *Giving WordPress its own directory* - it's probably a config setting or something in the theme (I'm guessing its setting a *base URL* for resources relative to the docroot, `/` instead of `/wordpress/` which you'll need as you've installed it in a sub-directory)... I'm no WP expert I'm afraid.

Comment: @PeterMatisko I tried the link you shared. It moved the whole wordpress site to my main domain. I want to access the wordpress site at http://localhost/wordpress. In this case, I am able to access the wordpress site at http://localhost. And even in this case, other web pages are not getting loaded properly.

Comment: @Nitesh, I am testing what you need on my localhost and there is no issue. It would be hard to diagnose remotely.  I am not sure i can help without access

Comment: @PeterMatisko Ohh, Okay. I need to make sure that we are on the same track. Can you provide me your .htaccess code in the root directory and in wordpress directory?

Comment: It worked. `RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]` was missing from .htaccess file. Thank you guys @CD001 @PeterMatisko

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My configuration:

domain: test.localhost

wordpress url:  test.localhost/wordpress

.htaccess in the wordpress folder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Apache settings for the subdomain (Wamp server under windows)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "e:\Sync\www\test"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias test.localhost

    <Directory "e:\Sync\www\test">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Nitesh, did it help for your issues?

Comment: Yes, It worked. `RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]` was missing from .htaccess file. Thank you, Peter.

Comment: Excellent! Good luck with the project :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while trying to modify a few absolute paths to relative paths. The problem was that I left an extra `/` at the start of the relative path.

**Correct Code:**

```
<a href="about">About</a>   
<!--The link goes to to http://BASE_URL/wordpress_subdirectory/about-->
```

**Errorneous code:**

```
<a href="about">/About</a>
<!--This href is relative to the 'Root'. It goes to http://BASE_URL/about-->
```